# how to use TingoDB in stead of MongoDB with Deployd?

Tags: openwrt, deployd, tingodb

We want to use deployd on our homemade device running OpenWRT.
As MongoDB would required too much memory, we want to use TingoDB in stead of MongoDB.
How to configure Deployd to do so?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I already did "npm install tingodb" then replaced the line
"mongodb = require('mongodb')" with "mongodb = require('tingodb')"

But it does not seem to be enough

Comment: I would like to publicly thank @andreialecu for his help.
It sounds like allowing to use TingoDB with deployd in stead of MongoDB would be possible.
I updated /lib/db.js following his recommendations and created a fork here: https://github.com/vpxavier/deployd/tree/myBranchWithTingoDB
Currently, the path for the data's location has to be hard coded in db.js

Comment: hi,how to install mongodb on openwrt？Can you teach me?